# what I cant splir the char of '(' using this regexp in javascipt

Tags: javascript, regex

the var codigo have the value ***int a,h;float b,c;a=b*(c+h);**

my regex is:

```
codigo = codigo.split(/(\b;|\b,|\b[=]|\b[+]|\b[-]|\b[*]|\b[/]|\b[(]|\b[)]|\bint|\bfloat|\bchar)/)
```

and as a output im getting this:

```
["int", "a", ",", "h", ";", "float", "b", ",", "c", ";", "a", "=", "b", "*", "(c", "+", "h", ")", ";", "$"]
```

```js
var codigo = 'int a,h;float b,c;a=b*(c+h);'
codigo = codigo.replace(/\s/g, '')
codigo = codigo.split(/(\b;|\b,|\b[=]|\b[+]|\b[-]|\b[*]|\b[/]|\b[(]|\b[)]|\bint|\bfloat|\bchar)/).filter(car => car != "")
console.log(codigo)
```

why after the **'*'** the **'('** isnt splitting right ? when the **')'** its doing correctly?

Comment: your code is giving proper output. [here is the link](https://jsbin.com/voyakuqufu/edit?js,console)

Comment: i sse that it should give me the proper output but for some reason it isnt working i did copy and paste your regex and it didnt work either

Comment: What is the actual output you want here?

Comment: almost the same as the one that im getting but the character '(' isnt splitting right

Comment: @SifatHaque - the string you used is different than the OP's. It is missing the `*`. I originally made the same mistake because the string in the question is different than the string in the StackSnippet.

Comment: @SolePanic - Please correct your question. The input strings are different.

Comment: i already did it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Regular Expressions**, since `.` represents *any character*, it should be enough to split by the following **regex**:

```
codigo = codigo.split(/(int|float|char|.)/);
```

and then remove the empty string elements, using `.filter(Boolean)`.

**Working Example:**

```js
var codigo = 'int a,h;float b,c;a=b*(c+h);'
codigo = codigo.replace(/\s/g, '');
codigo = codigo.split(/(int|float|char|.)/);
codigo = codigo.filter(Boolean);
console.log(codigo);
```

Answer (score 2):

The boundary between the `*` and `(` or `/` are non-word boundaries.

You need to change the lowercase `\b` to uppercase `\B` here:

`|\B[(]|`

```js
var codigo = 'int a,h;float b,c;a=b*(c+h);'
codigo = codigo.replace(/\s/g, '')
codigo = codigo.split(/(\b;|\b,|\b[=]|\b[+]|\b[-]|\b[*]|\b[/]|\B[(]|\b[)]|\bint|\bfloat|\bchar)/).filter(car => car != "")
console.log('index 14: ',codigo[14], ' index 15: ', codigo[15], ' array: ', codigo );
```